Where to use parse_html=True for GeoJsonPopup(fields that contain html text?
I have the below code block so far that reads data from json where popups function as expected, except they are just string text. Possibly this needs a for loop listener to parse html text fields from a json file so that they will be links instead of text?
I guessed as to where to put the parse_html because I'm new to web mapping, and could only find the map marker example in the second code block below.
popup = folium.GeoJsonPopup(fields=['FIELD THAT HAS HTML LINKS AS TEXT'], parse_html=True)

folium.GeoJson(
    Testing1,
    name = "Testing",
    style_function=lambda feature: {
        "fillColor": "red",  # Set the fill color
        "color": "#9e0000",  # Set the border color
        "weight": 2,  # Set the border weight
        "fillOpacity": 0,  # Set the fill opacity
        "fillColor":
        (
        ),
    },
    popup=popup,
    popup_keep_highlighted=True,

).add_to(m)

With the above attempted use of parse_html no changes happens, they remain as simply text, and there are no errors when I run the above block with parse_html in that position. I was hopeful that the fields containing html text links would now show up as links that could be clicked on within the popup tables.
Here is a map marker example I found below with parse_html, which not helpful so far for what I need, but is all I have to go by after many hours looking.
folium.Marker(     location=[40.7128, -74.0060],     popup=folium.Popup("<b>Hello, world!</b><br>This is a popup with HTML.", parse_html=True), ).add_to(m)
Thank you for any direction on this question.

I figured it out
